# Build a TCP proxy on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tcp

I'm trying to figure out how to build a TCP proxy on GAE (Google App Engine). I would ordinarily do it using twisted networking engine but GAE doesn't allow frameworks. I'm also pretty new to internet and networking technologies in general.

Basically I have a proxy server and I'd like to use GAE as a TCP proxy to relay everything to the primary proxy server. All the GAE front ends are connected to the back end by google fiber, so if I make the back end near the primary proxy server, it should make it super fast regardless of where I'm connecting from.

Unfortunately GAE doesn't allow me to control ports at all and everything that I'm reading either tells me how to configure a TCP proxy on a server that I'm in complete control of or how to configure a proxy where I type the url into a webpage in the browser. Something along the lines of making a personal http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy/ type of website.

I'd like to set it up so I can simply tell chrome to ignore certificate errors (it connects to a dynamic IP using HTTPS so there's no way to sign it but I trust myself) and put the proxy info into chrome.

Edit: I'd prefer to write it in python but I can do any language

Thanks in advance

P.S. Please don't give answers like just use GoAgent or tor or something. They don't fulfill my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simply trying to proxy HTTP requests like GoAgent does then have a look at the URLFetch documentation for Google App Engine.

[URL Fetch Python API Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/)

If you're trying to proxy anything else, then Daniel is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the sort of thing you can use GAE for.

I don't know where you got the idea that GAE "doesn't allow frameworks". Of course it does, anything that speaks WSGI (eg Django, Flask, Pylons) is fine. But GAE is a *web* platform: it's not an appropriate place to try and write any sort of bare-metal networking platform. Apart from anything else, bandwidth on GAE is fairly expensive.

And also I don't know where you think the GAE "front ends" are, as opposed to the "back ends". GAE is not split that way, AFAIK.

I don't really understand what exactly you are trying to do, but it sounds like a content delivery network (CDN) like Akamai might be more appropriate.

Comment: Google is trying to become a CDN. Look at 10:00 in this google released video on App Engine design. http://youtu.be/QJp6hmASstQ Also GoAgent is a service that runs through google app engine used to get around internet censorship. A proxy is exactly what it is. Also, here's a link to a google groups question about twisted where a google representative confirms that background services such as twisted won't work. http://goo.gl/dZuDJZ